# adb reboot not working

Tags: android-emulator, adb, reboot

I am using linux op and installed android sdk.

I have created a android emulator.

I open the android emulator and type `adb reboot`, the emulator hangs and nothing happens in the command prompt. It looks like it hangs

is there any verbose option to see what reboot is doing

Comment: I had to wait a while (~1 min) for `adb reboot` to succeed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `adb logcat`  from another terminal window.
`adb logcat` will provide info to you.

Answer (score 0):

late answer, try

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

then it will work